# Python- Convert string which have numbers and letters to float for np.list

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist, type-conversion, readfile

I have a text that I use for taking data. I want to take this "line" and make it numpy list. My data is string but it has numbers and E letters. Because of this I can't convert it to float and taking it to list.

```
import numpy as np
import re 


with open("FEMMeshGmsh.inp", "r") as file:  

     for line in file.readlines():
       if "+" in line:
           line = line[:-1]
           
           a = np.array(line)
           print(a)
```

```
10,1,0.0000000000000E+00
11,1,0.0000000000000E+00
26,1,0.0000000000000E+00
27,1,0.0000000000000E+00
80,1,6.2500000000000E+01
152,1,0.0000000000000E+00
153,1,0.0000000000000E+00
154,1,0.0000000000000E+00
155,1,6.2500000000000E+01
156,1,6.2500000000000E+01
157,1,6.2500000000000E+01
158,1,6.2500000000000E+01
159,1,0.0000000000000E+00
160,1,0.0000000000000E+00
161,1,0.0000000000000E+00
162,1,6.2500000000000E+01
163,1,6.2500000000000E+01
164,1,6.2500000000000E+01
165,1,6.2500000000000E+01
166,1,6.2500000000000E+01
424,1,1.2500000000000E+02
425,1,1.2500000000000E+02
426,1,1.2500000000000E+02
427,1,1.2500000000000E+02
428,1,1.2500000000000E+02
429,1,1.2500000000000E+02
430,1,1.2500000000000E+02
```

I tried this code but the output is not in the list. I tried to convert this string to float using astype. But  I took ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10,1,0.0000000000000E+00' this error.

Comment: The "+E00" isn't the issue at all, `float('6.2500000000000E+01')` = 62.5. The issue is the commas. How would you convert `'10,1,0` to float? Have you tried `split()` to split the line into a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```py
import numpy as np
import re 


with open("FEMMeshGmsh.inp", "r") as file:  
     for line in file.readlines():
       if "+" in line:
           line = line[:-1]
           line_array = line.split(",")
           number_array = line_array[-1].split("E+") 
           line_array[-1] = float(number_array[0]) * 10 ** int(number_array[1])
           a = np.array(line_array)
           print(a)
```

Comment: You don't need to split on `E`, Python `float` can handle "1.2E+01"

Answer (score 0):

```
In [757]: lines="""10,1,0.0000000000000E+00
     ...: 11,1,0.0000000000000E+00
     ...: 26,1,0.0000000000000E+00
     ...: 27,1,0.0000000000000E+00
     ...: 80,1,6.2500000000000E+01""".splitlines()
```

Just split the lines on the comma; conversion to floats is easy from that:

```
In [758]: lines1 = [l.split(',') for l in lines]

In [759]: lines1
Out[759]: 
[['10', '1', '0.0000000000000E+00'],
 ['11', '1', '0.0000000000000E+00'],
 ['26', '1', '0.0000000000000E+00'],
 ['27', '1', '0.0000000000000E+00'],
 ['80', '1', '6.2500000000000E+01']]

In [760]: arr = np.array(lines1,float)

In [761]: arr
Out[761]: 
array([[10. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [11. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [26. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [27. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [80. ,  1. , 62.5]])
```

Or just using list and `float`:

```
In [762]: lines[0].split(',')
Out[762]: ['10', '1', '0.0000000000000E+00']

In [763]: float(lines[0].split(',')[2])
Out[763]: 0.0

In [764]: float(lines[-1].split(',')[2])
Out[764]: 62.5
```